# RayTracing: When to Normalize a vector?

Tags: graphics, vector, linear-algebra, raytracing

I am rewriting my ray tracer and just trying to better understand certain aspects of it.

I seem to have down pat the issue regarding normals and how you should multiply them by the inverse of the transpose of a transformation matrix.

What I'm confused about is when I should be normalizing my direction vectors?

I'm following a certain book and sometimes it'll explicitly state to Normalize my vector and other cases it doesn't and I find out that I needed to.

Normalized vector is in the same direction with just unit length 1? So I'm unclear when it is necessary?

Thanks

Comment: This question can not be answered in the current form. It entirely depends on your implementation and the algebraic equations you use.

Comment: Can you perhaps common use case scenarios? or what kind of info I should add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr: Normalized vectors simplify your math.  They also reduce the number of very hard to diagnose visual artifacts in your images.**

> Normalized vector is in the same direction with just unit length 1? So
>   I'm unclear when it is necessary?

You almost always want all vectors in a ray tracer to be normalized.

The simplest example is that of the intersection test: where does a bouncing ray hit another object.

Consider a ray where:

```
p(t) = p_0 + v * t
```

In this case, a point anywhere along that ray `p(t)` is defined as an offset from the original point `p_0` and an offset along a particular direction `v`.  For every increment of parameter `t`, the resulting `p(t)` will move another increment of length equal to the length of the vector `v`.

Remember, you know `p_0` and `v`.  When you are trying to find the point where this ray next hits another object, you have to solve for that `t`.  It is obviously more convenient, if not always obviously necessary, to use normalized vector `v`s in that representation.

However, that same vector `v` is used in lighting calculations.  Imagine that we have another direction vector `u` that points towards a lighting source.  For the purpose of a very simple shading model, we can define the light at a particular point to be the dot product between those two vectors:

```
L(p) = v * u
```

*Admittedly, this is a very uninteresting reflection model but it captures the high points of the discussion.  A spot on a surface is bright if reflection points towards the light and dim if not.*

Now, remember that another way of writing this dot product is the product of the magnitudes of the vectors times the cosine of the angle between them:

```
L(p) = ||v|| ||u|| cos(theta)
```

If `u` and `v` are of unit length (normalized), then the equation will evaluate to be proportional to the angle between the two vectors.  However, if `v` is not of unit length, say because you didn't bother to normalize after reflecting the vector in the ray model above, now your lighting model has a problem.  Spots on the surface using a larger `v` will be much brighter than spots that do not.

Comment: My book actually tells me to keep my direction vector of my ray **not normalized**, because it would screw up when transforming my vector into the object space of each instance.

Comment: I have a feeling it is because scaling is not preserved.

Comment: @Setheron, well, there are two things that are in play here.  Imagine a direction vector that was normalized to be one meter long.  In that case, the value t will indicate how many meters you need to go to get to an intersection.  On the other hand, you might find it more convenient to deal in terms of "separation between eye point and target point" where t ranges from 0 to 1 (0 = eye ball and 1 = the intersection).  In the end, you need to understand the logic and the math.  Go with what works.

Comment: I understand now. It's the amount you move with each time interval. I guess as long as I understand when it's necessary to keep it normalized and not it will all be good! Thanks

Comment: @Setheron, glad to hear it.  Good luck!

Comment: I actually ended up not normalizing my vector so that I can transform it down my tree hierarchy with each node's transformation. If I restricted it to unit length, the intersection time I'd discover would be incorrect I think.

Answer (score 7):

**You never need to normalize a vector unless you are working with the angles between vectors, or unless you are rotating a vector.**

That's it.

In the former case, all of your trig functions require your vectors to land on a unit circle, which means the vectors are normalized.  In the latter case, you are dividing out the magnitude, rotating the vector, making sure it stays a unit, and then multiplying the magnitude back in.  Normalization just goes with the territory.

- If someone tells you that coordinate system are defined by n unit vectors, know that i-hat, j-hat, k-hat, and so on can be *any* arbitrary vector(s) of *any* length and direction, so long as none of them are parallel.  This is the heart of affine transformations.
- If someone tries to tell you that the dot product requires normalized vectors, shake your head and smile.  The dot product only needs normalized vectors when you are using it to get the angle between two vectors.

But doesn't normalization make the math "simpler"?

Not really -- It adds a magnitude computation and a division.  Numbers between 0..1 are no different than numbers between 0..x.

Having said that, you sometimes normalize in order to play well with others.  But if you find yourself normalizing vectors as a matter of principle before calling methods, consider using a flag attached to the vector to save yourself a step.  Mathematically, it is unimportant, but practically, it can make a huge difference in performance.

So again... it's all about rotating a vector or measuring its angle against another vector.  If you aren't doing that, don't waste cycles.

Comment: One extra point: there's a case specifically to avoid normalizing vectors when you don't need to. If you're using SIMD instructions that calculate the reciprocal square root (as in SSE, AVX, and NEON) when normalizing the vector, you'll want to avoid it in order to maintain some accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to normalize a direction vector whenever you use it in some math that is influenced by its length.

The prime example is the dot product, which is used in most lighting equations. You also sometimes need to normalize vectors that you use in lighting calculations, even if you *believe* that they are normal.

For example, when using an interpolated normal on a triangle. Common sense tells you that since the normals at the vertices are *normal*, the vectors you get by interpolating are too. So much for common sense... the truth is that they will be *shorter* unless they incidentially all point into the same direction. Which means that you will shade the triangle too dark (to make matters worse, the effect is more pronounced the closer the light source gets to the surface, which is a... very funny result).

Another example where a vector might or might not be normalized is the cross product, depending on what you are doing. For example, when using the two cross products to build an orthonormal base, then you must at least normalize once (though if you do it naively, you end up doing it more often).
If you only care about the direction of the resulting "up vector", or about the sign, you don't need to normalize.

Comment: The whole concept of a length of a vector is confusing to me when I think about it. If a vector is the concept of a direction in space, why would it's length even matter?

Comment: Well, that's just the problem. It _is not_ just a direction in space. It is a _length pointing in some direction_. (1,1,1) and (100,100,100) will point in the same direction, but they have different lengths (pythagoras formula). When you talk of a _normal_, you usually mean not just _any vector_, but one that has a length of exactly 1. This has the nice property that the math doesn't give strange, random results if you compare the directions between some points, but something that is solely dependent on directions.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer the opposite question. When do you NOT need to normalize? Almost all calculations related to lighting require unit vectors - the dot product then gives you the cosine of the angle between vectors which is really useful. Some equations can still cope but become more complex (essentially doing the normalization in the equation) That leaves mostly intersection tests.

Equations for many intersection tests can be simplified if you have unit vectors. Some do not require it - for example if you have a plane equation (with a unit normal) you can find the ray-plane intersection without normalizing the ray direction vector. The distance will be in terms of the ray direction vectors length. This might be OK if all you want is to intersect a bunch of those planes (the relative distances will all be correct). But as soon as you want to compare with a different distance - calculated using the normalized ray direction - the distance values will not compare properly.

You might think about normalizing a direction vector AFTER doing some work that does not require it - maybe you have an acceleration structure that can be traversed without a normalized vector. But that isn't relevant either because eventually the ray will hit something and you're going to want to do a lighting/shading calculation with it. So you may as well normalize them from the start...

In other words, any specific calculation may not require a normalized direction vector, but a given direction vector will almost certainly need to be normalized at some point in the process.

Comment: Here is my comment from above: My book actually tells me to keep my direction vector of my ray **not normalized**, because it would screw up when transforming my direction vector into the object space of each instance I am testing for intersection. This is the part that has me confused

Comment: I have a feeling it is because scaling is not preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are used to store two conceptually different elements: points in space and directions:

- If you are storing a point in space (for example the position of the camera, the origin of the ray, the vertices of triangles) you don't want to normalize, because you would be modifying the value of the vector, and losing the specific position.
- If you are storing a direction (for example the camera up, the ray direction, the object normals) you want to normalize, because in this case you are interested not in the specific value of the point, but on the direction it represents, so you don't need the magnitude. Normalization is useful in this case because it simplifies some operations, such as calculating the cosine of two vectors, something that can be done with a dot product if both are normalized.